# What is the difference between quoteplus and quotestar registers in vim?

Tags: vim

Can you explain the meaning of the following text from gui_x11.txt from vim help?

Note that the text in the "+ register remains available when making a Visual
selection, which makes other text available in the "* register.  That allows
overwriting selected text.

Answer (score 8):

The "+ register" is the vim equivalent to a CTRL+C in another program, while the "* register" is the "mouse selection and middle click" equivalent (in a Gnu/Linux OS).

So your sentence means that when you copied something in the "+ register", your visual selection in Vim is still available in the "* register".

Hope I've been clear enough.

Comment: I am working on gvim / windows 7. When I select a text from outside vim and do a "+p, I am able to paste that text inside the vim editor.  But if I select a text inside vim before doing "+p, vim is pasting the text selected inside vim instead of the text copied from outside vim.  Looks like text selection and copying is getting copied to both quotestar and quoteplus registers.  Are there any settings to change this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is what was described in the same documentation in the example:

> Examples: (assuming the default option values)
>
> 1. [Select](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#Select) an URL in
>      [Visual](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#Visual)
>      mode in Vim.  Go to your browser and click the   middle mouse button
>      in the URL text field.  The selected text will be inserted
>      (hopefully!).  Note: in Firefox you can set the
>      `middlemouse.contentLoadURL` preference to true in `about:config`,
>      then the selected URL will be used when pressing middle mouse button
>      in most places in the
>      [window](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#window).
> 2. [Select](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#Select) some text in your browser by dragging with the mouse.  Go to Vim and > press the middle mouse button: The selected text is inserted.
> 3. [Select](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#Select) some text in Vim and
>      [do](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html#do) `"+y`.  Go to
>      your browser, select some text in a textfield by dragging with the
>      mouse.  Now use the right mouse button and select "`Paste`" from the
>      popup menu.  The selected text is overwritten by the text from Vim.
>
> Note that the text in the
>   "[+](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#+)
>   [register](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/sponsor.html#register)
>   remains available when making a
>   [Visual](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#Visual)
>   selection, which makes other text available in the `"*`
>   [register](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/sponsor.html#register).
>   That allows overwriting selected text.

So if you have something in you `"+` register it will remain the same if you select something with Visual selection (that goes to `"*`.) **Note** that this behaviour can be altered see `:help 'clipboard'`.